# Finding sql records that do have one value, but not others

Tags: sql

I have a sql table, for the purpose of this post, we will say it has 2 columns, name and value. there are multiple name records with different value entries. There are certain situations where if a value exists for a name, a set of other values must also exist. I am trying to determine where that situation does not occur. For example, if a value of "combo" exists, then a value of "1" and "2" must exist to be in a correct state. I was trying queries like this one:

```
Select  Name
From    Table
Where   Value = "combo"
And Value Not Exists 
(
    Select  Name
    From    Table
    Where   Value IN ("1", "2")
)
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
select name  
from table  
where value in ('combo', '1', '2')
group by name
having count(distinct value) = 3
```

or

```
select name  
from table 
group by name
having sum(case when value = 'combo' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
and sum(case when value = 1 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
and sum(case when value = 2 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return `combo` if it exists in the table, but values `1` or `2` or both do not.

```
select name
from table
where value = "combo"
and (
 select count(distinct value)
 from table
 where value IN ("1", "2")
) < 2
```

Answer (score 0):

One interpretation of your question is:

```
 `forall name: exists (value = combo) => exists (value in (1,2))`
```

`A => B` is the same as `~A or B` and translated to SQL that becomes:

```
select distinct name from T T1
where not exists (
    select 1 from T T2
    where T2.name = T1.name
      and T2.value = 'combo'
)
or exists (
    select 1 from T T3
    where T3.name = T1.name
      and T3.value in (1,2)
);
```

Is this what you meant?